# How do I attach a link or image to a radio/select input element

Tags: webforms, input-formats

I want to attach an image-link to every input element.
Is it possible to do it on entity fields or on webform fields?
I prefer to it on server side.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "attaching an image to every input element".

Comment: I added an example to the post

Comment: If you're happy to write php, you can do this in a custom module, using hook_form_alter() and the ['#prefix'] form element property. Let me know if you need some help with that.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but I need it to be managed via UI because the customer want to control it. Is there an easy way to let the customer add a prefix?
And Do you sure that it's possible to add a prefix individually for each option?

Comment: Constructive critique: do you realize that this "image" may cause this question to be flagged as possible spam? If I was in your shoes, I'd try to hide the 'product' names/labels. Better still : replace it by another image that does not show any such "labels" ...

Answer (score 1):

ok, so then you need two parts both stored in a custom module:

1. an admin interface where the client can upload images for each relevant form element. Use drupal_get_form('FORM_ID') and loop through the form elements. Create a new admin form with image form elements corresponding to the webform elements. save the images and create a mapping table mapping the image urls to the form elements.
2. an invokation of hook_form_alter() adding prefixes to the webform elements as stored in your mapping table.

Answer (score 1):

The [Webform Select Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_select_image) module does exactly what you want to do. Here is a quote from the modules project page:

> The purpose of this module is to add an images select component for
>   webform (checkboxes or radios buttons).

Comment: Note submissions using this module use the image in the form result rather than the legend...

Answer (score 0):

For now I decided to use [Webform Options Markup Component](https://drupal.org/project/webform_optionsmarkup) module even it's kind of hacking.